# PhpStorm - showing the debugging tool

Tags: phpstorm

How to show the PhpStorm debugger/stack trace viewer after it's been replaced with a search, for example?

I'm talking about this:

[image]

Which gets hidden when running "show usages":

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to switch using tool window buttons. As an example:

[image]

If you have them hidden (e.g. to have more screen space etc -- this can be triggered using `View | Tool Buttons`) then you can still access them via `View | Tool Windows` menu.

[image]

Comment: I swear I looked at View -> Tool Windows and didn't see Debug :) thanks